# Which is the best way to update UI in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have **tab activity** which consists of 2 tabs. Each tabs have its own fragment which is dynamically created. I need to update fragment content from service. I am trying following way to **update UI of Fragment**

I've registered broadcast receiver on tab activity and calling fragment method but getting **Null Pointer Exception**

Is it good to recreate all the objects that were already intialized

```
mData = null;
mData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It's already been initialized but when broadcast receiver is getting called i need to reinitialize

Does this affect any kind of memory issue?

OR

I should register broadcast receiver inside my fragment.

Kindly help me to get the best solution.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no memory issue with reinitializing every time.  The garbage collector will take care of any of the old objects when they lose all references to them (reassigning mData to a new ArrayList).
2. I would still put the broadcast receiver in the fragment.  It will simplify things by taking the activity out of the loop since it doesn't need to get the broadcast.